# I want to get a variable in typoscript select Query

Tags: variables, typo3, typoscript, fluid-layout, typo3-9.x

The title says it all; I need a Typoscript SQL SELECT query with a dynamic WHERE clause.

I get the UID of the current logged in user with:

```
data = TSFE:fe_user|user|uid
```

But how can I use that in a database query?

I store the UID in a typoscript variable named `{userID}`.

That's my code so far. The Problem is Typoscript just merge the two values:

```
// User One has value: 50
// User Two has value: 32
// With this code the output is : 5032 ????

    lib.coins = CONTENT
    lib.coins {
        table = fe_users
        select {
            pidInList = 18
            where = uid
            andWhere.insertData = TSFE:fe_user|user|uid
            selectFields = coins
        }
        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {
            1 = TEXT
            1.field = coins
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: build real conditions. `where = uid` results in a condition consisting of just a number. no comparation, no field. the same with the `andWhere`. this will result (of course) in a strange query with  `SELECT .... WHERE 123 AND 546` (assuming uid is 123 and user|uid is 456)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make use of the `select` option [`markers`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Select.html#markers):

```
lib.coins = CONTENT
lib.coins {
    table = fe_users
    select {
        selectFields = coins
        pidInList = 18
        where = uid = ###UID###

        markers {
            UID.data = TSFE:fe_user|user|uid
        }
    }
    renderObj = COA
    renderObj {
        1 = TEXT
        1.field = coins
    }
}
```